# How can I get this timeframe script to work properly as it is throwing out random numbers

Tags: pine-script

I have the below script. the idea is that it will track and plot the accumulative volume for the day ( then reset to 0 when the new session starts)

the second part will then take the average volume for the ticker by taking the last 10 days average volume (from the daily)

finally because I want to know how SPY is doing relatively to the previous 10 days (is it at 100% of the average volume at 12:00 etc )which I thought the plot would do however it is throwing up some random numbers and spikes where as there should nexer be an instance where this drops other than at the end of the day/ start of the day

```
//@version=5
indicator('VOl calc Lines', '',false)
tf=input(title="Period",defval=10)//10 days

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////cumulative volume for the day
todayvol() =>
    cumTimeFrame = input.timeframe('D')
    is_new_day = ta.change(time(cumTimeFrame)) != 0 ? 1 : 0
    cnt_new_day = ta.barssince(is_new_day)and barstate.isrealtime and session.ismarket
    var todayvol1 = 0.0
    todayvol1 := volume + (is_new_day ? 0 : todayvol1)
    
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////volume average over 10 days (tf)
dailyvolav()=> 
    cumTimeFrame = input.timeframe('D')
    is_new_day = ta.change(time(cumTimeFrame)) != 0 ? 1 : 0
    cnt_new_day = ta.barssince(is_new_day)and barstate.isrealtime and session.ismarket
    var todayvol11 = 0.0
    todayvol11 := volume + (is_new_day ? 0 : todayvol11)
    ta.sma(todayvol11,tf)
 

plot(request.security("SPY", "5",(dailyvolav()/todayvol())*100))
```

I have working on this and still cant seem to find the issue. it seems to work when im on the ticker and timeframe is 1D but dosent work on the 5 min time frame. the figures are all wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer, it is due to not naming the broker in the security call (obvious when you know)